# where to download the crypt module for python 2.7 on windows?

Tags: python, python-2.7, crypt

I'm trying to start getting into python with a cyber security book, and it says that the crypt module comes standard with python, however, I doesn't import and I cant see it in the libraries folders.

I cant seem to download the module, Am I doing this wrong or am I being stupid?

Thanks :)

Comment: `crypt` is on [Unix](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unix.html). Are you on Windows?

Comment: If your question is explicitely about `crypt` module, just look at the post referenced by Peter Wood. If it is about crytpography there are the crypto services. From Python Library Reference Manual  *These modules are not distributed with Python but available separately. See the URL http://www.pycrypto.org/ for more information.*